# The proper age for a boy to start dating

Tags: halacha, marriage, age, shidduchim-dating

From a halachic viewpoint, what is the proper *age* for a boy to meet one's potential wife nowadays? (i.e. dating)

Comment: I dont think this is a halachic question; Jewish law does not regulate this. It is left to personal choice.

Comment: Pirkei Avot suggests that by age 18 one should be married. But, it doesn't state anything about "dating". Perhaps, at that time, couples first met under the Chuppa? (Hmmm ... sounds like Fiddler on the Roof, no?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the *Minchas Chinuch* (or perhaps it is the *Sefer Hachinuch*), the *mitzva* of פרו ורבו only applies at the age of 18, as in the *mishna* in *Avos* 5:22.  The *Gemara* in *Kidushin* 30a is somewhat critical of someone that waits beyond the age of 22 or 24; however, the exact age depends on the emotional maturity of the child, as per חנוך לנער על פי דרכו, "Educate the youth according to his way" (*Mishlei* 22:6).

So, to answer your question, the exact age depends on the individual, and generally varies between 18 and 24 to begin the search.  Obviously, one cannot be held accountable for marrying late if the search took a long time (אונס רחמנא פטריה, the *Torah* does not hold one liable for circumstances beyond his control).

*Kidushin* 29b discusses the ramifications of one who is learning, perhaps abroad, and *Rashi* and *Tosafos* have different interpretations of under which circumstances one could marry later because of learning *Torah*.  (I don't believe this would apply to non-*Torah* higher education, which is not a *mitzva* per se.)

Comment: It's not a Mishna but a Braysa attached to Avos.

Comment: @DoubleAA Chapter 6, *Perek Kinyan Torah*, is a *baraisa* attached to *Avos*.  Chapter 5 is part of *Avos* proper.  R' Tarfon's statement, בן שמונה עשרה לחפה, is *perek* 5, *mishna* 22.

Comment: That's mostly true, but that one "Mishna" 5:22 is not a Mishna but added in later. It's not in old editions. That's why the Rambam's commentary skips this "Mishna" http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&st=&pgnum=401&hilite= Note how the previous bit ends with " כן יהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלוהינו שתיבנה עירך בימינו, ותיתן חלקנו בתורתך, ועם עושי רצונך" as if it's the end of the work. See too the Shinui Nuschaot section in the above link, and look at this manuscript-based edition for instance http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h49.htm

Comment: That's interesting. I've never heard that before. Do you have a source for that? Your point about old editions, though - if *Chinuch* quotes it, it was obviously attached quite a while ago, before any **printed** editions.

Comment: The Chinukh doesn't explicitly reference it http://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.1 though some footnote person seems to think he did. That reference could easily be to the Gemara in Kiddushin.

Comment: I would like to explain the rashi and tosfos you mention on kiddushin 29b. There are three/four machlokes there. Does one have to support a wife if one is not living with her.  Does one have "tahara" if one is not living with her. Did people from Israel also study in Bavel.  Also were people in Israel rich and Bavel poor. @Menachem